# Strange VB.NET Winforms combobox behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

VB.Net solution in Visual Studio 2012

I have a combobox with databindings to a database table.
Let's call it the Manufacturer Table.
The table has 2 values:  ID, Name

My combobox fills correctly, with the DisplayMember set to Name, and ValueMember set to ID.  It returns the correct Valuemember when selected.  That all works as expected.
But here's the strange part...
When you select values in the combobox, it changes the display values inside the combobox.

Example:
Initial Values:

- Manuf A
- Manuf B
- Manuf C
- Manuf D
- Manuf E

After selecting Manuf C and clicking on the combobox down arrow again, the combobox now displays:

- Manuf C
- Manuf B
- Manuf C
- Manuf D
- Manuf E

Now I'll click Manuf E, and the combobox now displays:

- Manuf C
- Manuf B
- Manuf E
- Manuf D
- Manuf E

Can anyone tell me why it's doing this and what I can do to stop it from rearranging and overwriting my display values?

Comment: you probably have code in one or more combobox events changing/filtering or sorting the datasource

Comment: What is the dropdown style of your combobox?

Comment: It is a DropDownList

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the datasource or bindingsource of the combobox is not related to the same source as the data that you are trying to save.  Say you have a products bindingsource that has a foreign key to manufacturers.  Your data you want to save would look like this  Products->Manufacturers.  Your combo box must bind to an independent datasource that is derived only from your manufacturers table.